# $f(x)\in K[x]$ implies $\deg(f)\mid [E:F]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field, $f(x)\in F[X]$ irreducible, $n$ the degree of $f(x)$, and $E/F$ the splitting field of $f(x)$. I want to prove that $n\mid [E:F]$.

I try this by induction. $n=1$ is trivial.

Let $n+1$ be the degree of $f(x)$. Because $f(x)$ is irreducible, it has no roots. Let $\alpha$ a root of $f(x)$. Then $f(x)=(x-\alpha)h(x)$ in $F(\alpha)$. The degree of $h(x)$ is $n$.

Let $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ the dinstinc roots of $h(x)$, where $k\le n$. The splitting field of $f(x)$ is $E:=F(\alpha,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k)$.

This means $$[E:F]=[F(\alpha,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k):F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k)]\cdot [F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k):F]$$

By hypothesis induction $n\mid [F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k):F]$.

Still I don't see why $n+1$ must be divide $[E:F]$.

Could you give me any idea? Maybe it is another easy way.

Thank you.

Comment: @Mathgemini thank you! By the way, did you mean $[E:F(\alpha)]$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I messed this up a little. Below is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha\in E$ be a root of $f$. Then $f$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ since it is irreducible. So the degree of $[F(\alpha):F]$ is $n$. But this divides $[E:F]$ by the tower law.